# How to debug JavaScript in Spring application?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to go through tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ and want to debug JS code, how to do that?

Java code debug works fine.
I can debug in browser with debugger keyword in JS files, but I want to debug in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Nothing [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+idea+javascript+debug) ?

Comment: @mplungjan , no, that's how I usually use debug, but with spring boot I cant start JS debug, I get error 404 for bundle.js. If I start spring app bundle.js loads just fine...